# pep8- conituation line under indented for visual indent

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Im running a pep-8 on my eclipse and came across this error and not sure how to fix it..

```
'''
Created on Aug 31, 2015

@author: testuser
'''


def telemetry_client_show_alarm_history_testststsststst(id1, name):
    pass

show_alarm = telemetry_client_show_alarm_history_testststsststst('alarm_id',
                                            'tessdlkjsdsdsdsdsdsdsdt')
```

Error

```
E128 continuation line under-indented for visual indent
```

how can I fix this error?

note:the method names are dummy names to re-create this error in eclipse..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a function call is broken across lines, the 2nd and subsequent arguments should visually align with the first argument, like so:

```
show_alarm = telemetry_client_show_alarm_history_testststsststst('alarm_id',
                                                                 'tessdlkjsdsdsdsdsdsdsdt')
```

If that produces an undesirable result, such as lines that are too long, you can add a line break before the first argument, like so:

```
show_alarm = telemetry_client_show_alarm_history_testststsststst(
    'alarm_id',
    'tessdlkjsdsdsdsdsdsdsdt')
```

Comment: If I align then I get this error "E501 line too long (91 > 79 characters)"

Comment: Then try breaking the line before the first arg. See the recent edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a linting warning, the code itself should run fine. It means that the indented argument is not lined up with the enclosing paren, e.g.

```
show_alarm = telemetry_client_show_alarm_history_testststsststst('alarm_id',
                                                                 'tessdlkjsdsdsdsdsdsdsdt')
```

See also https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use shorter function names, that is the easiest solution.